# Left Join On CTE In MySql

Tags: mysql

What is the proper syntax for a Union and Left Join with a CTE in MySql?

Example:

```
With Test As (
    Select * from thistle
),
Select * from table1 t1
Union all
Select * from table2 t2
Left Join test ts
On t.userID = t1.userID
```

Comment: You need to include the table definitions for all three tables.

Comment: Is there no general rule of thumb of how the syntax should be?  I'd have to desensitize data in the 3 tables to produce DDL and inserts

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @JamesFisher You could just post the table structure (`DESCRIBE table_name`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably clearest to write the query using two CTEs:

```
WITH Test AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM thistle
),
T1T2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM table1 t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM table2 t2
)
SELECT *
FROM T1T2
LEFT JOIN Test ON T1T2.userID = Test.userID
```